# How to load Android Bitmap faster?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

I'm creating an app which needs to show a series of `Bitmap`s of a video's frames. The app uses `MediaCodec` to decode a video into a number of frames and gets `Bitmap`s of each frame to display them on `ImageView`.

The problem is that each `Bitmap`'s size is about 2~3MB (**Frame size is 1280 x 720**, the size of 720p video.) so that when the number of Bitmap is above 60~65, the app crashes due to the lack of memory. In order to avoid this problem I've been implementing the D tour algorithm which loads only `Bitmap`s that need to be displayed right now or soon. Basically I've been trying these methods.

#### 1. Load all `Bitmap`s in advance.

It's fast enough to meet my need but as mentioned the app crashes when the number of `Bitmap`s exceed 60~65.

#### 2. When extracting frames, save each frame into a `JPEG` file and load specific `JPEG`s into `Bitmap`s when needed.

I used [`BitmapFactory.decodeFile`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile(java.lang.String)) to load a `Bitmap` from a `JPEG`, but it was slow.

#### 3. When extracting frames, save whole frames into an [`MJPEG`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG) file and load specific "frame" (technically the byte array) into `Bitmap`s when needed.

I thought if I load `Bitmap` from the byte array itself the performance might be better. So when extracting frames, I created another metadata file containing information of each frame's byte indices and used that information to load `Bitmap`s when needed. [`BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray(byte[], int, int)) is used. I could see a slight improvement in speed but it is still insufficient.

What else can I try to boost up `Bitmap` loading in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your algorithm, some libraries such as [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) and [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) can handle that for you. As for the encoding/decoding speed, JPEG is probably your best bet at quickly flushing the Bitmap to disk because the file size is small and it could be backed by [hardware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895036/why-png-compression-is-that-much-slower-than-jpeg-on-android).

Some things you can try

1. If you have control over how the Bitmap is generated, use RGB565 to reduce memory consumption(up to 50% less memory becaue ARGB8888 is 32bit where as RGB565 is 16bit)
2. Create a smaller image and then scale it up later
3. Add `android:largeHeap=true` to manifest so you have memory to work with
4. LRU caching for the bitmap, this has been implemented in [Picasso's caching](https://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/LruCache.html) as well

If you want, manually compiling your jpeg library for your specific needs are possible but that would require non trivial work. Here's [something](https://github.com/suckgamony/RapidDecoder) you can test right now.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options, and your caching idea is smart. Off the top of my mind, here are a few things to try:

- Focus on why your images are so large. An image of that resolution should be able to be compressed smaller than 2 - 3 MB, and if its possible to encode the data into a more compressed image format, it will greatly reduce the memory footprint of your app and result in faster loading times
- If the full resolution photo isn't always needed, you can try resizing it on-demand and then later, if the full resolution photo is needed, you can load that
- Load images in the background so that when the user needs them, they are already there. This can be accomplished by extending your adapter and loading images in async tasks. There is a great example of this in the Google examples:
  http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html